# Understand EMI, EMC, and noise reduction on high power h-bridge driven output. Is my simulation done correctly? why is this circuit designed as such?

Tags: noise, mosfet-driver, h-bridge, emc, emi-filtering

I am trying to deconstruct and understand a circuit I came across with a filter in between the driving H-bridge and the large solenoid / magnetic actuator it drives. After looking at the pcb and determining the components and using a multimeter to get an idea of the values involved the circuit I came up with is as follows.

Actual Circuit:

[image]

Note: there are varistors in parallel with C1, C2, C4 and the solenoid side of the ferrite beads (L1, L2)

The h-bridge and PCB are in a metal enclosed and grounded box however the solenoid is outside and connected with several feet of wire. The filter must therefore to attenuate any noise / high frequency noise that the solenoid and wires might backfeed into the h-bridge causing mis operation of mosfets/transistors. However when I simulate a differential and common mode noise source I don’t get quite what I was expecting (low pass filter). I do see a low pass filter response when simulating common mode noise. But the differential mode noise response has a peak / resonance around the 50kHz.

Maybe I am not simulating the differential mode noise correctly. But if anyone has experience with EMI / EMC with inputs and outputs (high power outputs off h-bridges) I would greatly appreciate any insights or reading material you have.

Common mode noise circuit:

[image]

Common mode noise response:

[image]

Differential mode noise circuit:

[image]

Differential mode noise response:

[image]

Zoomed differential mode noise response:

[image]

Comment: I would inject noise at the source end (on the right) rather than at the load end. The main source of "noise" is likely to be unwanted harmonics of the driving signal. The trouble might be working out what parasitic capacitances (for example from the solenoid to surrounding objects) are important to determine the "load" behavior.

Comment: @ThePhoton if the h-bridge is really only firing / connecting the solenoid to the source for one uninterrupted brief pulse and then turning off would that still produce unwanted harmonics?

Comment: Yes, if the rising edges are faster than necessary, that might not strictly be "harmonics" but it's unwanted high-frequency content in the signal. Resonances due to parasitics can also worsen the effect. I also should have mentioned unwanted common-mode content (for example due to imperfect timing matching between the two sides of the H-bridge) as another main source of "noise".

Comment: @ThePhoton so I ran the same simulation but with the source connected on the H-bridge side and got relatively the same response in both the common and differential connection.

Comment: @Erv, The leakage inductances must be added to the common mode coil. See an equivalent model of a common-mode choke https://www.richtek.com/Design%20Support/Technical%20Document/AN008. It is likely that the resonance at 50kHz is attenuated by the leakage inductance that the differential mode current sees.

Comment: Your sources are peculiar: one is a million ohms, the other approximately zero. 150 or 50 ohms would be more typical for testing purposes. This will have a strong effect on the relative amplitude and peaking measured. You may want to look further back into the H-bridge as well: 50n across its output seems suspect and I wonder if more filter inductors aren't missing, or if it's supplied in an unusual way.

Comment: @Vincent k = 0.99 is ballpark close enough for most CMCs.

Comment: Also a warning about reverse engineering EMI solutions: almost no one is actually *good* at it. Most engineers spend a week or two at the testing lab, frantically swapping components around, and once they find a passing combination, that's it, that's the design. So you may well find incongruous combinations of parts, which might not be very good in general (peaks in response, or special cases for actual circuit impedances), but evidently were good enough to pass, considering everything else in the system as well.

Comment: @TimWilliams, Not always. For example : WE-FCLP Common Mode Power Line Choke https://www.we-online.com/en/components/products/WE-FCLP the leakage inductance represent approximaly 50% of common mode inductance. For a reliable simulation the input and output impedances are missing

Comment: @Vincent But those show ~2%? There can be more of course, but like I said, "most".

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write 5%. You are right.